# How to set a new color to Color Attribute using Rest API

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, rest-api, simple-product

Hey i'm begginer at Magento 2 and i want to set a new color type to the Color Attribute using REST API. Is it possible? I know this can be done using the admin menu, but i would like to do this using REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is link for magento rest API : https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/ .
And you can add color options by this api `/V1/products/attributes/{attributeCode}/options` POST. Instance is Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\OptionManagement-> add($attributeCode, $option);

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how the json would be? I didin't find a good example on this link that you send.

Comment: Hey, so in a more specific search on that link you send, i found the default json for this request. Would be something like this: {
  "option": {
    "label": "string",
    "value": "string",
    "sort_order": 0,
    "is_default": true,
    "store_labels": [
      {
        "store_id": 0,
        "label": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}